# How to solve value error regarding output tensors in Resnet model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, resnet

Was trying to implement a ResNet- CIFAR 10 model on Google Colab, using the code from https://github.com/jzuern/cifar-classifier. 
Instead of ReLU activation I'm using my own custom activation function. Here is the code:

```
 def fonlaaf(x):
     return x/(1-tf.exp(-x))
 def resnet_layer(inputs,
                 num_filters=16,
                 kernel_size=3,
                 strides=1, activation='fonlaaf',
                 batch_normalization=True,
                 conv_first=True):
    """2D Convolution-Batch Normalization-Activation stack builder
    # Arguments
        inputs (tensor): input tensor from input image or previous layer
        num_filters (int): Conv2D number of filters
        kernel_size (int): Conv2D square kernel dimensions
        strides (int): Conv2D square stride dimensions
        activation (string): activation name
        batch_normalization (bool): whether to include batch normalization
        conv_first (bool): conv-bn-activation (True) or
            bn-activation-conv (False)
    # Returns
        x (tensor): tensor as input to the next layer
    """
    conv = Conv2D(num_filters,
                  kernel_size=kernel_size,
                  strides=strides,
                  padding='same',
                  kernel_initializer='he_normal',
                  kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(1e-4))

    x = inputs
    if conv_first:
        x = conv(x)
        if batch_normalization:
            x = BatchNormalization()(x)
        if activation is not None:
            x = fonlaaf(x)
    else:
        if batch_normalization:
            x = BatchNormalization()(x)
        if activation is not None:
            x = fonlaaf(x)
        x = conv(x)
    return x


def resnet_v2(input_shape, depth=20, num_classes=10):
    """ResNet Version 2 Model builder [b]
    Stacks of (1 x 1)-(3 x 3)-(1 x 1) BN-ReLU-Conv2D or also known as
    bottleneck layer
    First shortcut connection per layer is 1 x 1 Conv2D.
    Second and onwards shortcut connection is identity.
    At the beginning of each stage, the feature map size is halved (downsampled)
    by a convolutional layer with strides=2, while the number of filter maps is
    doubled. Within each stage, the layers have the same number filters and the
    same filter map sizes.
    Features maps sizes:
    conv1  : 32x32,  16
    stage 0: 32x32,  64
    stage 1: 16x16, 128
    stage 2:  8x8,  256
    # Arguments
        input_shape (tensor): shape of input image tensor
        depth (int): number of core convolutional layers
        num_classes (int): number of classes (CIFAR10 has 10)
    # Returns
        model (Model): Keras model instance
    """
    if (depth - 2) % 9 != 0:
        raise ValueError('depth should be 9n+2 (eg 56 or 110 in [b])')
    # Start model definition.
    num_filters_in = 16
    num_res_blocks = int((depth - 2) / 9)

    inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)
    # v2 performs Conv2D with BN-ReLU on input before splitting into 2 paths
    x = resnet_layer(inputs=inputs,
                     num_filters=num_filters_in,
                     conv_first=True)

    # Instantiate the stack of residual units
    for stage in range(3):
        for res_block in range(num_res_blocks):
            activation = 'relu'
            batch_normalization = True
            strides = 1
            if stage == 0:
                num_filters_out = num_filters_in * 4
                if res_block == 0:  # first layer and first stage
                    activation = None
                    batch_normalization = False
            else:
                num_filters_out = num_filters_in * 2
                if res_block == 0:  # first layer but not first stage
                    strides = 2    # downsample

            # bottleneck residual unit
            y = resnet_layer(inputs=x,
                             num_filters=num_filters_in,
                             kernel_size=1,
                             strides=strides,
                             activation=activation,
                             batch_normalization=batch_normalization,
                             conv_first=False)
            y = resnet_layer(inputs=y,
                             num_filters=num_filters_in,
                             conv_first=False)
            y = resnet_layer(inputs=y,
                             num_filters=num_filters_out,
                             kernel_size=1,
                             conv_first=False)
            if res_block == 0:
                # linear projection residual shortcut connection to match
                # changed dims
                x = resnet_layer(inputs=x,
                                 num_filters=num_filters_out,
                                 kernel_size=1,
                                 strides=strides,
                                 activation=None,
                                 batch_normalization=False)
            x = tf.keras.layers.add([x, y])

        num_filters_in = num_filters_out

    # Add classifier on top.
    # v2 has BN-ReLU before Pooling
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = fonlaaf(x)
    x = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=8)(x)
    y = Flatten()(x)
    outputs = Dense(num_classes,
                    activation='softmax',
                    kernel_initializer='he_normal')(y)

    # Instantiate model.
    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=hparams.learning_rate),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
    tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.DEBUG)

resnet_model = resnet_v2((32, 32, 3), depth=56, num_classes=hparams.n_classes)

# Download and extract CIFAR-10 data
maybe_download_and_extract()

# training data
x_train, y_train = load_training_data()

# Validation data
x_val, y_val = load_validation_data()

# Testing data
x_test, y_test = load_testing_data()

# Define callbacks
callbacks = [
  tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=hparams.checkpoint_dir)
]

# This will do preprocessing and realtime data augmentation:
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=False,  # set input mean to 0 over the dataset
    samplewise_center=False,  # set each sample mean to 0
    featurewise_std_normalization=False,  # divide inputs by std of the dataset
    samplewise_std_normalization=False,  # divide each input by its std
    zca_whitening=False,  # apply ZCA whitening
    zca_epsilon=1e-06,  # epsilon for ZCA whitening
    rotation_range=0,  # randomly rotate images in the range (degrees, 0 to 180)
    # randomly shift images horizontally (fraction of total width)
    width_shift_range=0.1,
    # randomly shift images vertically (fraction of total height)
    height_shift_range=0.1,
    # set mode for filling points outside the input boundaries
    fill_mode='nearest',
    cval=0.,  # value used for fill_mode = "constant"
    horizontal_flip=True,  # randomly flip images
    vertical_flip=False)

# Compute quantities required for feature-wise normalization
# (std, mean, and principal components if ZCA whitening is applied).
datagen.fit(x_train)

# Fit the model on the batches generated by datagen.flow().
resnet_model.fit_generator(
    datagen.flow(x_train, y_train,batch_size=hparams.train_batch_size),
    epochs=hparams.n_epochs,
    validation_data=(x_val, y_val),
    workers=4,
    callbacks=callbacks)
```

Got the following error: ValueError: Output tensors to a Model must be the output of a TensorFlow `Layer` (thus holding past layer metadata). Found: Tensor("dense/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 10), dtype=float32)

The previous answers mostly to this error didn't work out. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error states, you have to pass the output of a Layer. As  fonlaaf() is an activation function with no state, you can use Lambda layer.

Replace,

```
def fonlaaf(x):
     return x/(1-tf.exp(-x))
```

with

```
def fonlaaf(x):
     return tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x/(1-tf.exp(-x)))(x)
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/#custom_layers
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Lambda